# 5941 Error The requested member of the collection does not exist Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good Day all. I'm far from a programmer however i need assistance finding out the error with this VBA script. It is run in a word document for repair order form. Its purpose is to increase the order number by one for each print. The counter updates a .txt file To identify the next number needed to print. That as far as my understanding goes. The code is below.

```
Sub serialNumberPrint()
'
' SerialNumber Macro
'
'
Dim Message As String, Title As String, Default As String, NumCopies As Long
Dim Rng1 As Range

' Set prompt.
Message = "Enter the number of copies that you want to print"
' Set title.
Title = "Print"
' Set default.
Default = "1"

' Display message, title, and default value.
NumCopies = Val(InputBox(Message, Title, Default))
SerialNumber = System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Users\GaleR\Documents\SettingsSerial.Txt", _
"MacroSettings", "SerialNumber")

If SerialNumber = "" Then
    SerialNumber = 1
End If

Set Rng1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SerialNumber").Range
Counter = 0

While Counter < NumCopies
    Rng1.Delete
    Rng1.Text = Format(SerialNumber, "000#")
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    SerialNumber = SerialNumber + 1
    Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

'Save the next number back to the Settings.txt file ready for the next use.
System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Users\GaleR\Documents\SettingsSerial.txt", "MacroSettings", _
        "SerialNumber") = SerialNumber

'Recreate the bookmark ready for the next use.
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Add Name:="SerialNumber", Range:=Rng1
End With

ActiveDocument.Save


End Sub
```

The debug brings me to this line:

```
 Set Rng1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SerialNumber").Range
```

I am at wits end and am not sure how to proceed. I apologize beforehand for my lack of knowledge but really do need the assistance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the expected behavior is and what the actual output is?  Does the script fail, output the wrong info, something else?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the bookmark SerialNumber does not exist in the document. If you select the place in the document (or template) and insert a bookmark with that name it should solve the problem.